# debug rock,paper, scissors game in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to program a rock, paper, scissors simulator game in Python. It works for the most part, but occasionally, when I enter my choice of rock, paper, or scissors for the input assigned to variable "guess," nothing is returned. Thank you!
Here is the program:

```
def main():
    print('This game is rock, paper, scissors')
    number=userguess()
    num=computernumber()
    result(number, num)
#computernumber function assigns number to rock, paper, scissors
def computernumber():
    num=random.randint(1,4)
    if num==1:
        print('Computer picks rock')
    elif num==2:
        print('Computer picks paper')
    elif num==3:
        print('Computer picks scissors')
    return num
#userguess assigns rock, paper, scissors to a number
def userguess():
    guess=input("Choose, 'rock','paper',or 'scissors:") #<- this input prompt
    if valid(guess):
        if guess== 'rock':
            number=1
        elif guess== 'paper':
            number=2
        elif guess== 'scissors':
            number=3
        return number
    else:
        print('Please choose a valid response')
        return userguess()
def valid(guess):
    if guess=='rock' or guess=='paper' or guess=='scissors':
        result= True
    else:
        result= False
    return result
def restart():
    again=input('Play again? (y/n)')
    if again=='y':
        main()
    elif again=='n':
        print('Goodbye')
    else:
        print('please enter y or n')
        restart()
#function to display result
def result(num,number):
   if number==num:
       print('Tie')
       restart()
   elif number==1 and num==2:
       print('you won!')
       restart()
   elif number==1 and num==3:
       print ('you lost!')
       restart()
   elif number==2 and num==1:
       print('you lost!')
       restart()
   elif number==2 and num==3:
       print('you won!')
       restart()
   elif number==3 and num==1:
       print('you won!')
       restart()
   elif number==3 and num==2:
       print('you lost!')
       restart() 
main()
```

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is a better place for this.

Comment: Hi, is my answer below solving your problem? Glad if you show some response.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here.

```
#userguess assigns rock, paper, scissors to a number
def userguess():
    guess=input("Choose, 'rock','paper',or 'scissors:") #<- this input prompt
    if valid(guess):
        if guess== 'rock':
            number=1
        elif guess== 'paper':
            number=2
        elif guess== 'scissors':
            number=3
        return number
    else:
        print('Please choose a valid response')
        # return userguess() 
        # You returned a function which is None
        userguess()
```

Hope this solved your problem.

Also, I want to suggest some shortcuts to shorten the code. For example, the above part can be shorten as follows:

```
str2num = {'rock': 1, 'paper': 2, 'scissors': 3} # can be defined globally

def userguess():
    guess=input("Choose, 'rock','paper',or 'scissors:") #<- this input prompt
    if valid(guess):
        return str2num[guess]
    else:
        print('Please choose a valid response')
        userguess()
```